# What is the correct way to write multiple trailing closures in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, trailing

I keep getting an error from swift playgrounds that it can't find the "missing argument for  parameter 'closure' in call."

```
func someFunc(closure: () -> (), closure2: () -> ()) {
    closure()
    closure2()
}

someFunc() {
    print("Calling from closure()")
} closure2: {
    print("Calling from closure2()")
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Your example is better than the official one in _The Swift Programming Language_ for a beginner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiple trailing closures are a new Swift 5.3 beta feature. Your code **compiles and runs correctly** in Xcode 12 beta using Swift 5.3 beta, as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

It is probable that the environment in which *you* are running does not have a Swift 5.3 beta compiler.